# Is there a way to lock an encrypted drive from the command line?

Tags: command-line, encryption, usb-drive

I have created an encrypted drive in which to store sensitive files. I'm wondering if there is a command line tool to unmount the encrypted drive and lock it. If there is, I was going to create a launcher to go in my dock so I can click it and the command will be executed without ever having to open the command line.

I used the command `sudo apt-get install cryptsetup` and went into the application `Disks` and selected the disk I wanted formatted and selected `Encrypted, compatible with Linux system (LUKS, ext4).`

I created a file in `gedit` called `lock` and copied it into `/bin` so I can run it as a single command. In the file is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo umount /mnt/luks-79a537ae-8eed-42a3-be85-7c54b920d4a2
sudo cryptsetup luksClose /dev/mapper/luks-79a537ae-8eed-42a3-be85-7c54b920d4a2
```

I ran `sudo visudo` and added this line to the file:

```
amolith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get, /sbin/cryptsetup, /bin/umount, /bin/lock
```

I saved it, exited, and, now, when I run `lock`, I am still prompted for my password even though the commands should not require the root password now (AFAIK).

Comment: I assume you're using LUKS?

Comment: Yes, but we need to know the encryption technology.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I added the information.

Comment: @AndroidDev I added the information.

Comment: Where is the information @Amolith?

Comment: @George at the bottom.

Comment: @Amolith that isn't still clear, "went into `disk` (which disk) and formatted" please run `lsblk -i` and paste into your question

Comment: @George - cryptsetup is LUKS. There must be a graphical front end but I agree the partition and crypt name is unclear.

Comment: @George at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are using LUKS . You need to know the name of the name of the partition, where it is mounted, and crypt name, it is in `/dev/mapper`

To mount (decrypt)

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdxy name_of_crypt
mount /dev/mapper/name_of_crypt /mount_point
```

To unmount (encrypt)

```
umount /mount_point
cryptsetup luksClose name_of_crypt
```

You may need to run those commands as root, ie sudo, so my advice is to configure sudo to run cryptsetup without a password.

Note: scripting mount / unmount of the encrypted data sort of defeats the purpose of encrypting in the first place. I would leave it as is ;)

See [How to script a mount command involving a dm-crypt / luks volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136345/how-to-script-a-mount-command-involving-a-dm-crypt-luks-volume) but , IMO, the answer in that question is insecure as you password is now in plain text. You could use expect to automate as well

https://www.lifewire.com/linus-unix-command-expect-2201096

Comment: I'm looking at [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/116757/8-ways-to-tweak-and-configure-sudo-on-ubuntu/) to configure sudo so I don't have to enter my password for `cryptsetup`. I can't find where `cryptsetup` be in the filesystem though.

Comment: `which cryptsetup` or `sudo updatedb && locate cryptsetup | grep bin`

Comment: It doesn't now, though. I wrote the script, it executes fine, `cryptsetup` executes without sudo, but umount does not (even when added to visudo) and, when I run `ls` in `/bin`, `umount` is highlighted red.

Comment: I have named the file `lock` and and copied it into `/bin` and marked it as executable. When I run `lock`, I'm prompted for the password and I don't want to be.  I've figured about that the issue is with `umount` but I don't know why I'm prompted for it when `umount` is already added to `visudo`.

Comment: you would have to post your sudo configuration and never hurts to post the commands you ran so we may check your syntax.

Comment: Should I make this into another question ot should I just add the information to this one?

Comment: Add in the commands you ran to your question , at the bottom

Comment: I added them at the bottom.

Comment: Change `sudo cryptsetup luksClose /dev/mapper/luks-79a537ae-8eed-42a3-be85-7c54b920d4a2` to `sudo cryptsetup luksClose name_of_crypt` rather than device. Do those commands work outside your script ?